# how to know a total commit of a collaborator

Tags: git, github

I'd like to know how many contribution of my collaborator. So I need know how many code write by himself and push to github. However, in github, there are also merge message will disturb me.

Is there a way in github or in git that I can know a collaborator actually commit code in a certain time? ( in every branch )

**update**
Can I see the diff of non-duplicated commit of this collaborator? ie. some other person's commit will also show in merge commit.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm not entirely positive. Check out http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/ though, it is what we use to track contributions, working hours of the day, etc..

Answer (score 5):

[`git shortlog`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shortlog.html) is the tool you're looking for. Use:

```
git shortlog -s
```

to get the summary of commits by user.

Answer (score 3):

Github actually does this for you in the Graphs section of the repository. Both the "Contributors" and "Impact" tabs include #commits, +lines/-lines for all non-merge commits.

Edit: just realized you wanted data for all branches, Github's graphs only report on the master branch. I don't know of any way to get all branch information from Github.

Comment: You're falsely assuming everyone who uses git also uses github.

Comment: @YuvalAdam no, the question asked if this was possible in github or git.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I added the github tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Github now (April 2013) proposes a way to visualize the umber of commits per collaborator, with the project **[Pulse](https://github.com/zmoazeni/csscss/pulse)** ("[Get up to speed with Pulse](https://github.com/blog/1476-get-up-to-speed-with-pulse)")

> **Pulse will show you who has been actively committing and what has changed in a project's default branch**:

[image: Pulse]

> You can find the link to the left of the nav bar.

[image: Link]

However, this is only **over a period of time**:

- 24 hours
- 3 days
- 1 week
- 1 month

So it isn't a way to get a collaborator's activity over the full life of the project.